# AndEngine: Fatal exception in GLThread: IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, andengine

I'm writing a custom dialog window for my AndEngine's BaseGameActivity and sometimes, when dialog have to dissapear, app crashes with this error:

```
08-15 09:49:16.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1572): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
        at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDrawChildren(Entity.java:1008)
        at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDrawChildren(Entity.java:1000)
        at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:993)
        at org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedDraw(Scene.java:233)
        at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:875)
        at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawScene(Engine.java:517)
        at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:509)
        at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:154)
        at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:617)
        at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:549)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found that it may happen when you trying to detach child in a background thread, so you have to use this code everytime you want to detach something:

```
activity.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scene.detachChild(child);
    }
});
```

Comment: are you sure that all detaching are in runOnUpdates? And, may be there's another reason for this error? It worked for me.

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm not sure about that. cuz my game is getting bigger w/ alot of source code..

I decided to make a patch for this case to avoid further errors. please take a look here if you interesting. https://github.com/rgv151/AndEngine/commit/749e5a2a8de907e8efbe40f2f84e19c4cd5b07a1. thanks

Comment: May be I'm looking in a wrong direction, but I didn't noticed any changes in detaching methods except formatting.

Comment: Yea formatting is annoying.. You can find changes  in onManagedDraw method

Comment: I had some "game reset-view code" in my AndEngine app .. that was having a similar crash (from original post).  When I wrapped the refresh call in it in `runOnUpdateThread(..)` .. the crash went away.  Thanks!