# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 13, size is 13

Tags: java, android, andengine

Im getting some weird error which crashing my android app. Its a quiz app. So when user answer 2/3 question correctly then click the next button this it crash. and show index 13 error. But i couldn't figure out where to fix/ look for. here is my code snippet.

```
public Vector<Sprite> defaultTile;

private void GameResults()
{
    if(result.equals("right"))      
    {           
        GameOver();
        Log.e("Gaa", "Right Here ->");
    }
}

private void GameOver() {
{
    for (int i = 0; i < defaultTile.size(); i++) {
        defaultTile.get(i).setVisible(false);               
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < defaultTile.size(); i++) 
    {
        unregisterTouchArea(defaultTile.get(i));                
    }
    questionText.detachSelf();   
}   

@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent event, ITouchArea area, float posX,
        float posY) {

    if(event.isActionUp())
    {
        if(area instanceof Sprite)
        {
            Sprite sprite = (Sprite)area;
            int userData = (Integer) sprite.getUserData();
            switch(userData) 
            {
            case BTN_NEXT:                              
                if(gameState.equals("alpha") && tickBg.isVisible())
                {                       
                    countdown.cancel();                         
                    GameResults();  
                }           

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log cat details is like this

```
08-09 13:30:50.246: W/dalvikvm(919): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 9
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDrawChildren(Entity.java:1008)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDrawChildren(Entity.java:1000)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:993)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.shape.Shape.onManagedDraw(Shape.java:120)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:875)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDrawChildren(Entity.java:1008)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDrawChildren(Entity.java:1000)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:993)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedDraw(Scene.java:233)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:875)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawScene(Engine.java:517)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:509)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:154)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:617)
08-09 13:30:50.276: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:549)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my full class file http://jquery404.com/file/GameScene.txt

Comment: At which line exactly error occurs? I feel you shouldn't get exception in the code which you have posted.

Comment: Please give the proper code

Comment: Somewhere you have an arraylist, of size 9, and a get call to that list is trying to get an item at index 9. For a size 9 arraylist, the highest index will be 8, as the indexes start at 0. Ie the 9 items in the list will have indexes 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.

Comment: Could be a threading issue somewhere. The Entity class isn't thread safe.

Comment: @PradeepSimha i have updated my code. code crashes after Log.e("Gaa", "Right Here ->"); this line.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967400/andengine-fatal-exception-in-glthread-indexoutofboundsexception?rq=1

Comment: @perp  here is the CLASS http://jquery404.com/file/GameScene.txt. I have UI Thread is that the problem

Comment: @jquery404, is this the correct code you have posted? because your tile and stacktrace are different.

Comment: @PradeepSimha yes that is the class. also the full project http://jquery404.com/file/enfamil/premium/ here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In programming indexes often start at 0, so if you have 9 items, the highest index would be 8.

The actual error is being thrown from some code within the library you are using

```
org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDrawChildren(Entity.java:1008)
```

It is likely that you are changing the list in a separate thread whilst the library is also interacting with the list.

---

From the [gcode project](https://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/Entity.java?r=9d1c7c0a5e53fce791b8411ac541fd74efc55f93);

```
    public void onManagedDrawChildren(final Camera pCamera) {
            final ArrayList<IEntity> children = this.mChildren;
            final int childCount = children.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    children.get(i).onDraw(pCamera);
            }
    }
```

As this is running in a separate thread, it is likely that you are removing an object from the children `ArrayList` while the loop is iterating. To fix this you should call your changes to the children `ArrayList` like jmr499485 explains in his answer.

[java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 13, size is 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148097/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-invalid-index-13-size-is-13/18148283#18148097)

The only item in your code I can see that would be causing this is the statement `questionText.detachSelf();` which you have used in many places. You should instead use;

```
runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    questionText.detachSelf();
}
});
```

Comment: but I didnt use anything like this :( here is the full class http://jquery404.com/file/GameScene.txt

Comment: here is the full project link http://jquery404.com/file/enfamil/premium/ @Robadob

Comment: That line is inside the library, it is called from the OpenGL render loop. I'll extend my answer

Comment: @jquery404 I've included what I think should fix it now.

Comment: @ Robadob nice explanation. and really that was the problem. ur solution worked. thanks a bunch mate.

Comment: @Robadob I am not detaching/attaching any objects but still I am getting this error. I am using object visibility and unregistertoucharea though. Can that cause this issue. If not can you please tell what might?

Answer (score 2):

This typically happens when you remove something from the screen and don't do it on the updateThread. Make sure that any place you are removing items that you call it like this

```
runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   //remove/detach your stuff in here
}
});
```

See this similar question - [How can repair this error? "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824236/how-can-repair-this-error-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception/9824583#9824583)